# Make addprefix arguments

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can someone explain the $(x)/*, .c* arguments
in the addprefix call here:

```
  SRC := $(foreach x, $(SRC_PATH), $(wildcard $(addprefix $(x)/*,.c*)))
```

with SRC_PATH := src
and files 'file.c' and 'file.h' in src, $(x)/* expands to src/file.c and src/file.h
and it would seem appending .c* would result in src/file.c.c and src/file.h.c
however SRC results in src/file.c
which is what we want but how does the addprefix call with $(x)/*,.c* arguments resolve to this ?

Comment: *"appending .c* would result in src/file.c.c"* Why? `$(addprefix $(x)/*,.c*)` is essentially a roundabout way of saying `$(x)/*.c*` (since `x` is always a single word in `foreach`).

Comment: foreach handles multiple values for x so no not 'since x is always ...'

Comment: Yes, it splits the input to words, meaning each value is exactly one word.

Comment: That's not the reason $(x)/*, .c* resolves to $(x)/*.c*

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to addprefix are concatenated verbatim prior to wildcard expansion resulting in
src/*.c*
which is then wildcard expanded.

There is effectively no need for the addprefix call in the context of setting SRC except possibly for clarity. :)

The code comes from a Makefile template at github
https://github.com/TheNetAdmin/Makefile-Templates/blob/master/SmallProject/Template/Makefile

Pretty good overall.